# Sort Search results alphabetically for People Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

After trying and failing to find some way to make a semi decent looking company directory with ootb parts, we've decided to just redirect people to _layouts/15/search.aspx/people, which works fine, but they appear to be sorted in no discernible order. Is there a way to change the results to be sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

You can not customize the search results as we used to do in the classic search result page as mentioned here.

However, you can use the **PnP Modern Search web part** as described in this post **[SharePoint Online – Search Options Today](https://searchexplained.com/sharepoint-online-search-options-2019-july/)**.

You can find the details about Pnp Modern Search from the below link.

**[PnP Modern Search solution](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/)**